# Passing array from node.js/express to jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here..

questions.js

```
  questions = [];
  questions.AA = 'First'
  questions.BB = 'Second'
  questions.CC = 'Third'
  res.render('questions', { title: questions[CC], questions: questions });
```

questions.jade

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p #{questions.CC}
  each question in questions
   p= question
```

Rendered

```
<body>
<h1>Third</h1>
<p>Third</p>
</body>
```

So

```
  each question in questions
   p= question
```

Doesn't seem to be working as I would expect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an array and then stored values into alphabetic indices rather than integer indices.  As such, `each` will not loop over them.  You probably mean to define `questions` like this:

```
questions = []
questions[0] = 'First'
questions[1] = 'Second'
questions[2] = 'Third'
```

Or, more idiomatically:

```
questions = [
    'First',
    'Second',
    'Third'
]
```

You’ll have to figure something out to replace how you were getting the `title`, but this should fix the loop.